# Glitch in my autocomplete to show jquery validation error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Hope this question is usefull.

> In my autocomplete success I make my input hidden value **1** to avoid
>   jquery validation and append the current customer name to the
>   particular input field and all are working fine.
>
> My glitch is if supposed user manually delete the value of input field
>   which have current customer name, I want to show jquery validation
>   error. But how can I show that??. Because In my autocomplete success I
>   made the hidden value **1**. So its failed to show the error and I cant check that in keyup or keydown function, Beacuse using that input id I already written the autocomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#apendexistingCustomer").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: '{{ url("/getexistingcustomer") }}',
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (ui.item.label == 'This customer is not in our records.') {
        $('#apendexistingCustomer').val('');
        $('#existcustomers').val('');
        $('#create').valid();
        swal("This customer is not in our records.", "", "warning");
      } else {
        $('#apendexistingCustomer').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#existcustomers').val(ui.item.key);
        $('#create').valid();
        getCustomerDet(ui.item.key);
      }
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      selectFirst: true;
      event.preventDefault();
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).autocomplete("widget")
        .appendTo("#results").css({
          'position': 'static',
          'width': '100%'
        });
      $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', '9999999');
      $('.ui-autocomplete').addClass('srchuser-dropdown');
    }
  }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li style='height:60px;'><span class='srchuser-downname'>" + item.label + "</span></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item).appendTo(ul);
  };

});
```

> this is my function to fetch customer details using autocomplete

```
protected function getexistingcustomer() {
  if (Request::ajax()) {
    $data = Request::all();
    $searchVal = $data['term'];
    if ($searchVal != '') {
      $searchResult = customers::searchCustomerAutoComplete(trim($searchVal));
    }
    $finalArr = array();
    if (!empty($searchResult)) {
      foreach($searchResult as $vk => $sf) {
        $finalArr[$vk]['label'] = $sf['firstname'].
        ''.$sf['lastname'];
        $finalArr[$vk]['key'] = 1;
      }
    } else {
      $finalArr[0]['label'] = 'This customer is not in our records.';
    }
    print json_encode($finalArr);
    exit;
  }
}
```

*customer Input field*

```
<div class="row" id="selectcusDiv">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label><sub>*</sub>Customers</label>
      <div class="select-container">
        <input type="text" id="apendexistingCustomer" name="apendexistingCustomer" class="form-control fieldcls">
        <input type="hidden" id="existcustomers" name="existcustomers" value="" class="form-control fieldcls">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Jquery Validation*

```
$('#create').validate({
  ignore: [],
  rules: {
    existcustomers: 'required'
  },
  messages: {
    existcustomers: 'please enter'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript add a change listener to the autocomplete element, and check for an empty value. If the value is empty, set the "avoid validation" flag hidden input to `0`, then use a required validation rule on that element.

```
$("#apendexistingCustomer").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).val() == ""){
        $("#validateFlag").val(0)
    }
});
```

Comment: $("#apendexistingCustomer").autocmplete({ }); But I already use that id

Comment: Yes. That's why I used it. Elements can have multiple event listeners.